# I need a javascript for loop it should print 10 to 1 like it should print still 1

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript for loop it should print 10 to 1 like it should still 1.

My JS Code:

`var b = "";
    var inc = "";
    var k = 10;
    for(a = k;a >= 1; a--){ 
     for(i=k; i<=1; a++)
     {
      console.log(parseInt(inc)); 
     }
    }
    console.log(parseInt(b));`

What am expecting is: 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
7 6 5 4 3 2 1
6 5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1
3 2 1
2 1
1

Comment: No, you need to understand that this site is not about you dropping requirements and other people doing the coding for you. You start by showing us the code you wrote so far!

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: sorry i forgot to post code,
var b = "";
var inc = "";
var k = 10;
for(a = k;a >= 1; a--){ 
 for(i=k; i<=1; a++)
 {
  console.log(parseInt(inc)); 
 }
}
console.log(parseInt(b));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following loop,

```
for (i = 11; i > 1; i--) {
    for (j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        console.log(j)
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Nikhil Patel thank you so much

Comment: This will only work if it doesn't matter that each number is on different lines, which is different to the specified requirement

Answer (score 2):

```js
var max = 10;
while (max--) {
 var str = [];
 for (var current = max+1; current > 0; current--) {
  str.push(current);
 }
 console.log(str.join(" "));
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer, gives the exact output that was requested

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work. It has an empty string that has 10 to 1 added to it first time round the loop. Then for each iteration within the second loop it takes 1 away from k (so the numbers added is decreased each time). and console logs the string.

```
var intString = "";
var k = 10;
for (i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
    for (j = k; j > 0; j--){
        if (intString == ""){
            intString = j;
        }
        else {
            intString += " " + j;
        }
    }
    console.log(intString);
    k--;
    intString = "";
}
```